# How to disable Loggings of Apptentive in Xcode console?

Tags: ios, xcode, apptentive

[Apptentive](http://www.apptentive.com/) seems like a good addition to have.  However it pollutes the Console with so many messages, that is unnecessary to see every time. It is distracting me from seeing important debug messages elsewhere.

Only an extract:

```
2015-05-10 10:15:45.134 xNews[34355:4228197] Loading ATSwizzle_NSObject_Bootstrap
2015-05-10 10:15:45.134 xNews[34355:4228197] Loading ATSwizzle_UIViewController_Bootstrap
```

According to the docs it's possible to disable them:

```
#import "ATConnect_Debugging.h"
[ATConnect sharedConnection].debuggingOptions = ATConnectDebuggingOptionsNone;
```

This doesn't work at all. I still get to see all those debug messages I don't care about.  Any advice please?

Answer (score 2):

The Apptentive `debuggingOptions` property does enable/disable some debug features, however it's true that we aren't tying that in with the log levels.

```
// #import "ATConnect_Debugging.h"
[ATConnect sharedConnection].debuggingOptions = ATConnectDebuggingOptionsNone;
```

I will make a note to add a new `debuggingOptions` option to silence all logging for an upcoming version of the SDK.

Apptentive **does** allow control over log levels via the `ATLog.h` file and preprocessor macros:

```
AT_LOGGING_ENABLED = 1
AT_LOGGING_LEVEL_INFO = 1
AT_LOGGING_LEVEL_DUBUG = 1
AT_LOGGING_LEVEL_WARNING = 1
AT_LOGGING_LEVEL_ERROR = 1
```

By default, release configuration of the Apptentive SDK will log only the `warning` and `error` log levels. Debug builds will log the more verbose `info` and `debug` levels.

In your Xcode project you should be able to set `AT_LOGGING_ENABLED = 0` to silence all Apptentive warning. Or toggle the log levels as you see fit.

[image: Apptentive logging preprocessor macros]

Thanks for using Apptentive! Let me know if you need any assistance with this.

Comment: This is 4 years old, in the documentation for Apptentive I still don't see anything about having the ability to turn any logging off.So this was never added? Is this answer still relevant or the method described is out of date?